# Retrieving data from a Datatable in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a data able that has the three columns: Username Password and Name.
I have a login in screen that checks that checks the username and password to allow for access or not. I am trying to display the Name of the user onto another Form, but what I have is not working.

The program runs until i press login and then an IndexOutOfRangeException is shown. I feel like I am not calling the correct cell that the data is located in, but I can not figure it out. I am very new to data tables.

Login Form:

```
namespace Inventory_Program
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public string name;

        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        /*
         * Used when user accepts to login. username and password must be correct or error message will display
         * Using a table in sql form. 
         */
        private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\brand\Documents\Data.mdf; Integrated Security = True;");
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Count(*) From Login where Username='" + usernameTextfield.Text + "' and Password = '" + passwordTextfield.Text + "'", connection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {

                name = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                this.Hide();
                MainGUIPanel mainview = new MainGUIPanel();
                mainview.Show();  

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Incorrect! Try Again!");
            }

        } //end of login button


        //can canel out of login in screen, closes window.
        private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        } //end of cancel button


        public string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

MainGuiView:

```
    namespace Inventory_Program
{
    public partial class MainGUIPanel : Form
    {

        Login login = new Login();

        public MainGUIPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //runs the current time and data
            currentTime.Start();

        }

        //Method is adding a horizontal line to the top panel
        private void topControlPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
            graphics.DrawLine(pen, 1091, 93, 00, 93);
            graphics.Dispose();

            nameLabel.Text = login.getName();

        }

        //allows for the current time and date to be displayed in the top panel
        private void currentTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

        }

        private void inventoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you meant `name = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();` here since indexes are zero-based. `[0][3]` would be trying to access a **fourth** column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Count(*) From Login where Username='" + usernameTextfield.Text + "' and Password = '" + passwordTextfield.Text + "'"
```

Puts only one item in your adaptor: a table in it with nothing more than a number (from Count(*) at dt.Rows[0][0].

You would want something like:

```
Select UserName From Login where Username='" + usernameTextfield.Text + "' and Password = '" + passwordTextfield.Text + "'"
```

See Below! This is very vulnerable to all them hackers out there!

and

```
name = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

A word of caution, and this is important: I really encourage you to look up sql server injection attacks. Your code is very vulnerable to this. A marginally experienced programmer could log into your application or wipe out your database without credentials, just by typing some code in your username or password field.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am going to look over sql server injection attacks and work on rewriting my code. Thanks for the input. I'm new to sql and I'm trying to learn as much as I can. Once I have it completely I am going to post it here. Would you mind to review it and give suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Yup! I'll keep an eye on your post. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The error is located at: name = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();.

You select: count(*), which only will return 
1column.

You need to select the columns you want to show. 
you don't need to count the results since your where clause should select distinct results. Instead check if the datatables rows.count is larger than 1.